ldap3 2.9.1 and python 3.10.7 connection issues
I am trying to query email addresses and aliases from AD. Sometimes I get no entries back from an email even though the email exists in AD. I ran a loop 100 times to test an email and 7 times I got no entries. I am running python 3.10.7 and ldap3 2.9.1 . Does anyone know if there is an existing bug or can it be because my VM is not part of the domain?
# Search active directory for the user to see if they are still with the company 
def search_active_directory(email, domain, ad_password, ad_username):
    missing = 0
    # Connect to domain
    domain_connect = Connection(Server(domain, get_info=ALL),user=ad_username, password=ad_password, auto_bind=True)
    
    # Combine the parts into the full search filter
    search_filter = create_search_filter(email)

    # Define the attributes
    attributes = ['mail', 'proxyAddresses', 'userPrincipalName', 'targetAddress']
    the_emails = []
    
    for x in range(100):
        search_base = "DC=amer, DC=com"
        domain_connect.search(search_base, search_filter, SUBTREE, attributes=attributes)
            
        if len(domain_connect.entries) == 0:
            missing += 1
    return missing
    

# Help function to return the string for the search filter
def create_search_filter(email):
        user_account_control = "(!(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2))"
        mail = f"(mail={email})"
        proxy_addresses = f"(proxyAddresses=*{email}*)"
        user_principal_name = f"(userPrincipalName=*{email}*)"
        target_address = f"(targetAddress=*{email}*)"
        return f"(&{user_account_control}(|{mail}{proxy_addresses}{user_principal_name}{target_address}))"


Are you always connecting to the same domain controller? Do the failures correlate with the IP address that domain_connect.socket.getpeeraddr() reports?

I don't get a failure when the code runs, just no entries sometimes. I only ever connect to the domain once so I assume from there it uses the same domain controller throughout the 100 iterations unless otherwise.
